# General approach for SQL script execution in Java

Tags: java, sql, plsql, oracle11g, prepared-statement

The functionality that discussed within this question is to execute the given SQL script. The content of the script is intended to be defined by the user during application runtime. The script can be whether one `INSERT` statement or a sequence of complex `PL/SQL` statements. Since the input available during runtime (eventually as String instance) it should be executed through Java.

Current approach is wrapping user input with a `PreparedStatement` and to execute it. This solution works for the existing test cases. The main concern is to provide the full functionality of the used database that might be not covered by tests, i.e. solution that is closest to passing the same user SQL script into database vendor's provided console.

I'm wondering are there any not envisaged limitations in current approach with `PreparedStatement`? Is there any better general approach for SQL script execution via Java?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Do you want to simply run everything, are you trying to create something like http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: Are security vulnerabilities a concern here? Are adequate restrictions in place to prevent the script from doing anything potentially unwanted or dangerous? (E.g. via the user's privileges in the database?)

Comment: @SteveChambers there is no vulnerabilities concerns, since user modifies his own database and fully responsible for it. The main concern is to provide the full functionality of the database in the most efficient way.

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Just give them Oracle SQL Developer and a login with the appropriate permissions

Comment: @Bohemian Got what you mean, please consider that the user provided script will be executed in scheduled manner and coupled with the application reporting therefore it won't be a solution to give a role with appropriate permissions to the user.

Comment: @pavel you would need a pretty compelling use case not to use cron with a script. There's no way I would let "users" specify any query whatsoever to be run, let alone periodically. It will probably end in tears.

Comment: @Bohemian understand that, it's a business requirement and the decision is out of the scope of my responsibility, the circumstances of this approach are considered by the teammates and managers.

Comment: Why don't you expose phpMyAdmin as web interface or if you want to give the opportunity to work online you could use IndexedDB to store the database in the browser and then sync with your server database

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is a broad design question but I think that there are several steps that could be done:

- **SQL script parsing and recognition**: You need to be able to detect which type of SQL script you have: PL/SQL, DML, DDL, CDL, TCL, multipart separated by ";" etc.
- **Statement building**: for each type of sql script you need to be able to execute the statement with java.
- **Parsing the result**. You need to be able to collect the returned in SELECTs and optionally parameters returned by functions or number of affected/inserted rows.
- **Error handling**: you need to be able to report what happened to the SQL Script when things didn't worked as expected.

Please consider:

- This seems like the programming of a SQL Client. If not please explain what do you want to do. Do not use this as the connection layer in a normal application. It will be extremely inefficient and vulnerable to SQL injections (It is much more complicated than just scaping commas)
- You may want to call functions o execute queries with external parameters.
- This does not includes the user interfaces features like Syntax highlighting. Parameters interfaces, etc...

Comment: Performed the update of the question, @borjab please consider the new version of the question

Comment: I built an [open source project](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer) that might help with many of the above steps.  It can split statements similar to how SQL\*Plus would, classify statements so you know what to do with them, remove unnecessary semicolons (some statements need them and some don't), and provide feedback similar to SQL\*Plus (e.g. "5 rows merged." for a MERGE statement).  It's all in PL/SQL but it should be possible to call it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

The first limitation of `PreparedStatement` that comes to mind - you won't be able to register an `OUT` parameter(s) of a stored procedure, you may wish to look into `CallableStatement` interface.